# How do I send a long notification with Bluez, example?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I need to send a long (let's say 10Kb) notification from Bluez 5.37 on my Linux device to a mobile phone.

My implementation is based on `src/shared/gatt-server.c`.

I cannot find an example of this in Bluez. `src/shared/gatt-server.c`, `bt_gatt_server_send_notification()` is strictly trimming the packet to MTU-1 and discards the rest. I must need an output queue for this, like in `gatt-client.c`. `bt_gatt_client_read_long_value()` looks like an example of what I need, but for long characteristic reads.

1. Is there a way to send a long notification compatible with majority of Bluetooth 4.0 Android phones? It [requires a bit of collaboration on the phone side - sending a ATT_READ_BLOB_REQUESTS](https://community.freescale.com/message/441553#441553), AFAIS.
2. Or is there a generic packetization library that will work over 20-byte-sized packets?
3. Another way I can think of is to create another characteristic, use Notification messages for short messages and, er, notifications that "Hey, there's a long message, read it from that characteristic".

Which way is better? Does an example of any of the three ways exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entitled to disclose the code, but here's the basic idea of what I did. I use a [tools/bgatt-server.c](https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/tools/btgatt-server.c) as an base for my peripheral.

### To send a long message:

- Save the `notification_buffer` being sent and the `notification_position` in the `server`'s fields;
- Implement a `bt_gatt_server_send_notification_with_callback()` function in `gatt-server.c`. It should do the same as `bt_gatt_server_send_notification()` but have extra `void *user_data` and `bt_gatt_server_destroy_func_t destroy` arguments, and pass them to `bt_att_send()`. This will enqueue the next invocation of `destroy` callback when the bluez output queue becomes free.
- Implement a `bt_gatt_server_destroy_func_t` that calculates the next chunk to be sent from server's `notification_buffer` and `notification_position` fields, send them with `bt_gatt_server_send_notification_with_callback()` and passes `server` as `user_data` and itself as the `destroy` callback.

### To reassemble the message on receiving end:

- I split the long message with my own packetizer/depacketizer.
- I use a header: 1 byte - packet's `messageId` and 2 bytes for packetId - this way, one can have messages up to 17*65536 bytes length. Plus, this leaves the opportunity to re-request a packet for reliable delivery in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I do this for Bluez:

```
PRLOG("Send Notify, %d bytes\n", send_len);
do {
  if (RPService.valid) {
    send_res = bt_gatt_server_send_notification (pCharac->server->gatt, pCharac->handle,
                                                     pTx, mMIN(send_len, mBLE_TRANSFER_SIZE));
  } else {
    break;
  }
  if (send_res) {
    pTx += mBLE_TRANSFER_SIZE;
    send_len -= mBLE_TRANSFER_SIZE;
  } else {
    PRLOG("  Notify write failed...wait\n");
    usleep(mTX_WAIT);
  }
} while (send_len > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! In other words, you send multiple notifications and the thread will be blocked, correct? How long a data did you send? Did you try to send a 10k notification, and receive messages at the same time?